# Filter array to remove the duplicate records based on multiple columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Below is the input array I have:

```
let inputArr = [
    {
        "supplierId": "1",
        "baseSupplierId": "71277",
        "supplierName": "Supplier 1",
        "partNumber": "4018992",
        "partDescription": "Description 1"
    },
    {
        "supplierId": "2",
        "baseSupplierId": "71277",
        "supplierName": "Supplier 2",
        "partNumber": "4018992",
        "partDescription": "Description 2"
    },
    {
        "supplierId": "3",
        "baseSupplierId": "71277",
        "supplierName": "Supplier 3",
        "partNumber": "4019030",
        "partDescription": "Description 3"
    },
    {
        "supplierId": "4",
        "baseSupplierId": "71277",
        "supplierName": "Supplier 4",
        "partNumber": "4018291",
        "partDescription": "Description 4"
    },
    {
        "supplierId": "5",
        "baseSupplierId": "71277",
        "supplierName": "Supplier 5",
        "partNumber": "4018992",
        "partDescription": "Description 5"
    }
]
```

And I want to have an array as output which will have unique values based on column "baseSupplierId" and "partNumber" and also if there are multiple records with the same "baseSupplierId" and "partNumber" then get only the first one and remove other duplicates.

So I want the ouput array as follows:

```
let outputArr = [
        {
            // This is the item that had multiple records with the same "baseSupplierId" and "partNumber" and now only one should come in output
            "supplierId": "1",
            "baseSupplierId": "71277",
            "supplierName": "Supplier 1",
            "partNumber": "4018992",
            "partDescription": "Description 1"
        },
        {
            "supplierId": "3",
            "baseSupplierId": "71277",
            "supplierName": "Supplier 3",
            "partNumber": "4019030",
            "partDescription": "Description 3"
        },
        {
            "supplierId": "4",
            "baseSupplierId": "71277",
            "supplierName": "Supplier 4",
            "partNumber": "4018291",
            "partDescription": "Description 4"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Sounds pretty doable. What's your question, exactly?

Comment: You forgot to add the JavaScript code you're having issues with. Please read [ask], then [edit] with a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Use a set to get uniqueness

Then chain all relevant fields

```
let uniqueCombinations = new Set();
let outputArr = [];

for (let item of inputArr) {
    let combination = item.baseSupplierId+ "#SOME_SEPARATOR#" + item.partNumber;

    if (!uniqueCombinations.has(combination)) {
        outputArr.push(item);
        uniqueCombinations.add(combination);
    }
}
```

Insert into output array if not exist in set.

Comment: Right. And supplier ID `71277` and part number `4019030` now yield the same key as supplier ID `7127` and part number `74019030` and you have introduced an incredibly hard to trace bug into the system. At the bare minimum, you should consider adding a separator between supplier ID and part number when constructing the key.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert (using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)) to [new Map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) (by unique property) and then extract the Map's `.values()` :

```js
const getUniquePartBySupplierId = (arr, id) => {
  const outputMap = inputArr.reduce((m, item) => {
    if (!m.has(item.partNumber) && item.baseSupplierId === id) {
      m.set(item.partNumber, item);
    }
    return m;
  }, new Map());
  return [...outputMap.values()];
};

const inputArr = [
  {"supplierId": "1","baseSupplierId": "71277","supplierName": "Supplier 1","partNumber": "4018992","partDescription": "Description 1"},
  {"supplierId": "2","baseSupplierId": "71277","supplierName": "Supplier 2","partNumber": "4018992","partDescription": "Description 2"},
  {"supplierId": "3","baseSupplierId": "71277","supplierName": "Supplier 3","partNumber": "4019030","partDescription": "Description 3"},
  {"supplierId": "4","baseSupplierId": "71277","supplierName": "Supplier 4","partNumber": "4018291","partDescription": "Description 4"},
  {"supplierId": "5","baseSupplierId": "71277","supplierName": "Supplier 5","partNumber": "4018992","partDescription": "Description 5"},
];

const output = getUniquePartBySupplierId(inputArr, "71277");
console.log(output);
```

Comment: readability of code is key! Your answer works for someone more advanced in JavaScript but not for beginners, so I suggest you edit your answer and do a proper return of the map object (`m`)

Comment: also, OP asks that the filtering happens for both `baseSupplierId` and `partNumber` so I will downvote you, sorry.

Comment: Thank you @ElvisAdomnica Absolutely valid remarks. Edited taking them in consideration.

Comment: nice, I reset my downvote then :)

Comment: I however cannot upvote your answer because you are assuming that the array will contain only 1 `baseSupplierId` that you pass to your function. The OP is asking to filter out any object that has the same pair of `baseSupplierId` and `partNumber` as other objects. Their input array contains only one such duplicates to keep the example simple.